# POI 3.7 java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError when instantiating a Font

Tags: websphere, apache-poi

I am getting a java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError with the following snippet:

```
Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
Font arial = workbook.createFont(); // java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError thrown here
```

I am using POI 3.7 with WebSphere 7 Portal Server. The same code (and as far as I can tell, the same jars) worked with Netbeans console application. It also seems that the 3.7 jar is the only one in the classpath. The project also uses JasperReports 4.1.2. Can I provide more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost certain that you have an older version of POI on your classpath

There's a section in the [POI FAQ](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006) that covers this very case. You'll want to use the code from there to identify where the extra copy of POI is coming from, and zap the old jar

Comment: You are right. `jakarta-poi.jar` is loaded from PortalServer\lwo\prereq.odc\shared\app