# Export data to Excel Part By Part

Tags: spring-mvc, jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I have a huge dataset value in JRDatasource object and am not able to export it to Excel as it will give me memory out of space error. So am planning to split the JRDatasource object and export the data part by part. Any idea or suggestion on how to implement this? Or any other way suggested also fine for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about JRDataSource, but I'll offer another solution.
Take a look at [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) library  which enables you to create excel files on-the-fly.

So you can read from the data source element by element and persist them on a excel file.

Comment: And my application server is websphere... So it wont support any Apache libraries..

Comment: You don't need an Apache web server to use Apache libraries. It should work fine with WebSphere too, as the library has nothing to do with the Servlets etc.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995824/poi-3-7-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror-when-instantiating-a-font

Comment: I tried this. Same error. I have around 38000 rows and 60 column of data. Even Apache POI is not able to help me. I even increased JVM size and checked. No use.

Comment: I think you can use sollution described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16157704/jasper-print-java-heap-space-memory